# what gnome packages (applications) are missing in ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: gnome

As it is, what gnome applications are missing in ubuntu 12.04? (edit: What programs are in the gnome package of ubuntu - which is not installed automatically?)

And will there be any advantage of installing them?

Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your question to be more specific?  I am assuming you are asking what software comes as standard with 12.04 compared to another distro you are familiar with

Comment: @StephenMyall I edited my question.

Comment: @user27515 - your question is unclear - missing from what?  compared to what? what desktop-environment are you referring to? if you install the gnome-package - it will install whatever the dependencies are.  What extra information are you looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no "gnome packages" missing.  I am still unclear what you are asking.  If you are planning to upgrade to 12.04 a list of the software that is in installed as part of the distrubution is listed here and on many other sites including www.ubuntu.com .

But like all Ubuntu distributions you have the Software centre where to can browse and download what packages you need